# Adding active class to div when url hash matches with specific div

Tags: javascript

I have a page with a horizontal accordion. This is done with some css and Javascript that adds the class `active` on the panel that's clicked. You can find the very basic version of it here: https://codepen.io/kubuskwal/pen/JjJjGmo

Now I should make it so that when the url has a #hash parameter, for example site.com/mypage#red, the panel with class `red` should automatically also receive the class `active` upon loading the page and thus be expanded.

Unfortunately my knowledge of Javascript is still very limited and while it may seem relatively simple, I can't seem to make it work. So far I only got this, which works, but it only adds the active class to the first panel.

```
const currentUrl = window.location.hash
if  (currentUrl == "#red") {
    document.querySelector(".panel").classList.add("active");
}
```

It would be better if I could make it compare `currentUrl` with the classes inside the panel divs, and if one of them has a class that is a match with `currentUrl`, it should add the active class to that div. But I spent an entire day trying to figure out how to do this, with no result :(. There are many similar (but not the exact same) questions with solutions here and I've looked at all of them, but most are with jQuery and I'm limited to vanilla Javascript unfortunately.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How are you getting hash `#red` in the URL?
will you add or does it should come automatically when we click on the div?

Comment: It will be used as a page highlighting different promotions (every panel represents one), and say I want to share one of the promotions on facebook, I need to be able to link to the page and have the corresponding panel automatically opened. After the user has landed on the page, they are free to close the panel and click on different ones to discover the other promotions. When accessing the page 'organically' through the website instead of a link with #hash, all of the panels should be in non-active state. Hope that clears it up!

Comment: i have added my answer can you look into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested this locally with your javascript and it looks like you had the querySelector set up wrong. Change it to the following:

```
if  (currentUrl === '#red') {
    document.querySelector(".red").classList.add("active");
}
```

Updated:

```
const currentUrl = location.hash
const classSelector = currentUrl.replace('#','.')

if (currentUrl) {
  document.querySelector(classSelector).classList.add("active");
}
```

Comment: Ahhh of course, I was hugely overthinking it with wanting to add the active class to the div containing .panel and the corresponding color-coded class, but I could of course just target .red instead of .panel. D'oh! I was able to repeat this code for #blue, #green, #yellow etc and it works exactly how I wanted. It's not exactly DRY code though, as I'm sure there's way to just compare the strings (barring the # and .), but that's something to irerate on next :D. Thank you so much!

Comment: No worries, happy to help!

Have updated it a little so you don't need to hard code the values in-------:

 const currentUrl = location.hash
const classSelector = currentUrl.replace('#','.')

if (currentUrl) {
  document.querySelector(classSelector).classList.add("active");
}

Comment: Ohhh perfect! Wow, actually it was so simple... I still got a long way to go. Thanks, I've learned something new again :D

Answer (score 0):

if url contain #red then add class active and if url not contain and page still has class active with red so need to remove it

```
    const currentUrl = window.location.hash;
    if (currentUrl == "#red") {
        document.querySelector(".red").classList.add("active");
    }
    else{
        if (document.querySelector(".red").classList.contains('active')) {
            document.querySelector(".red").classList.remove('active');
        }
    }
```

In a More simplified way!
if just want to add class

```
const currentUrl = window.location.hash;
    if (currentUrl == "#red") {
        document.querySelector(".red").classList.add("active");
    }
```

Comment: Ah I'm sorry that wasn't clear, but it should only trigger on first load. If the user accesses the page normally, all the panels should start in non-active state. If they land on the page with a #red hash for example, it should start with the red panel opened, but they are free to close it afterwards and open/close the other ones. Your code would definitely be useful if that wasn't the case though, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Add this javascript code to your script

```
let selectedDiv = window.location.hash;
selectedDiv = selectedDiv.substring(1);
const selectedPanel = document.querySelector("."+selectedDiv);
if (selectedPanel) {
    selectedPanel.classList.add('active');
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you, that has the exact outcome I needed. I wish I could mark two answers as best. I think @Jacob's approach is a little more elegant by using replace, as that got the job done with fewer lines of code, but honestly both approaches are perfect :)!

Answer (score 0):

A compact way could be the following, using the `?.` operator to avoid error when the element is not found

```js
const selector = window.location.hash.replace('#', '.');
if(selector) {
    document.querySelector(selector)?.classList.add("active")
}
```

Notice that you have to check whenever the selector is an empty string because otherwise querySelector will throw a `DOMException`.

if you can provide a default value for the selector, the snippet can be even shorter

```js
const selector = window.location.hash.replace('#', '.') || '.the-default-element';

// ...

document.querySelector(selector)?.classList.add("active")
```